# templates not being served, could it be .htaccess?

Tags: templates, htaccess

I've tried the tips here:
[404 on Every Template and TPL group](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14320/404-on-every-template-and-tpl-group)
and here:
[404 error on all templates but homepage after removing index.php](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/404-error-on-all-templates-but-homepage-after-removing-index-php)

I can access the index by using the default url (on my localhost, port 8040)

```
http://localhost:8040
```

But I cannot access any other templates:

```
http://localhost:8040/cursos   
http://localhost:8040/programas
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 ^(cursos) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|js|css|crmi_cms|themes|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And here is my template directory structure:

```
expressionengine    
    templates    
        default_site    
            cursos.group    
                index.html    
            programas.group    
                index.html    
            site.group    
                index.html
```

site.group/index.html is default site home page.

I've even tried moving the cursos.group index to the site.group and renaming it to cursos.html.
Still nothing...

Please help me.

Comment: why do you have "RewriteEngine on" in the middle of .htaccess? It must be on the top. And try to add "RewriteBase /". Also, just for sure - are you sure that your server is used .htaccess? What systems you use on the server? Apache/iis/NGINX+php-fpm?

Comment: I have updated the .htaccess and it still won't serve the page, says "The requested URL /cursos was not found on this server."

Comment: BTW, using Wampserver 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally worked. I double checked that mod_rewrite was installed, too.

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(admin|images|system|themes|index\.php|admin\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond $1 ^(cursos|programas|testimonales|salondelafama|enhonor|registro|resources|calendario|TNA) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you get the templates to render if you leave index.php in your URL? 
eg

> localhost:8040/index.php/cursos

If so then it is your .htaccess. Max is right about the order of your .htaccess file. Also, you could try adding a '?' in your RewriteRule directly after index.php

```
eg RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

A fairly reliable method of removing your index file is in the EE docs here - have you tried it?
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html#exceptions

Comment: 1. No it does not show with index.php in the URL. 2. I tried with a ? and still no go. 3. The link you gave is in one of the answers I tried.

Comment: Actually, I just tried it again with index.php like this: /index.php/cursos and it served the page. Not sure why it worked this time. I changed the .htaccess to this http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html#create-an-htaccess-file and it still doesn't work without index.php. Adding the ? didn't help either.

Comment: Try looking at this solution, it worked for this WAMP user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938330/unable-to-remove-index-php-on-expressionengine-wamp-installation#answer-11906830

Comment: @Pennzizzle - just tried in httpd-vhosts.conf, not work. It is already set like that in httpd.conf.

Comment: Also tried adding `RewriteBase /` still not working.

Comment: No more suggestions? I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this now old topic, I had a similar issue. While the original poster found the solution for their case, in my case the answer from BellamyStudio worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938330/unable-to-remove-index-php-on-expressionengine-wamp-installation#answer-11906830, updating the vhost.conf file, or in my case the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, to "AllowOverride All" for the directory where my site was hosted.

```
<Directory /the/path/to/my/webroot/>
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow, deny
  Allow from all
</Direcory>
```

In other words, my apache configuration was completely ignoring my htaccess file. Setting "AllowOverride All" made apache use the htaccess file in the webroot.

**Side note:** An easy test to see if your webserver is ignoring your htaccess file is to just add some junk data (a random string of letter for example) to the top of the htaccess file in the webroot, and then reload the website. If the result is an error (usually an "internal server error") then your webserver IS using the htaccess. Otherwise, the webserver IS NOT using the htaccess.